# Saving date and time to database

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I'm working on small windows form .net project where we need to build the appointment scheduler. Below is the screen mock of what the UI should look like.

[image]

The user should be able to select either AM, PM or OWH irrespective of hours. Or, he can choose specific hours from drop down.

I've a question on what would be the best approach to design the database for this. Initially I was thinking just using the Date and Time however, this would not work as 
it would be hard to store the AM/PM or OWH slots (without hour portion).

I'm thinking of doing below, any suggestions and best practices will be much appreciated:
1. Create Slots Table which basically contains:

```
SlotID  | Description
1       | AM
2       | PM
3       | OWH
4       | 00
5       | 02
....
```

2. Create Appoinment Table which contains below:

   AppointmentDate | SlotID |......

   04-02-2014  |   1|......

   04-03-2014  |   5 |......

Any other suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Your appointment time should be stored as DateTime field in Sql Server [if this is your DB]. You can separate date and time on your screen but combine them to save it in database. And later you just need to parse it to display it the way you want it.

Comment: how would you differentiate 00:00 as AM or hour. Note application needs to show both AM/PM/OWH and 24 hours.

Comment: time Range. Start 12 AM end 12 PM - this is your AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion is to store the type of time that is being stored.

Have an additional table for `TimeType`:

```
TimeTypeId | TimeTypeDescription
1          | AM
2          | PM
3          | OWH
4          | Time
```

Then change the `Appointment` table to do:

```
AppointmentDate | TimeTypeId | TimeOfDay (nullable)
2014-02-04      | 1          | (null)
2014-02-05      | 4          | 7 
2014-02-06      | 4          | 19
```

You only care about the TimeOfDay if the appointment has the right `TimeType`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, if you want to use it the way you have designed (for whatever reason), I would save it as starttime and endtime, that way for example can be AM = starttime 6 and endtime 18, and if the user selects 15 (for example) you can save it as starttime 15 endtime 16. I guess that way you can keep time ranges, from hour to hour, or larger ranges as AM, PM.

Hope that help you.